# Python regex string matching?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm having a hell of a time trying to transfer my experience with javascript regex to Python.

I'm just trying to get this to work:

```
print(re.match('e','test'))
```

...but it prints None. If I do:

```
print(re.match('e','est'))
```

It matches... does it by default match the beginning of the string? When it does match, how do I use the result?

How do I make the first one match? Is there better documentation than the python site offers?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`re.match` implicitly adds `^` to the start of your regex. In other words, it only matches at the start of the string.

`re.search` will retry at all positions.

Generally speaking, I recommend using `re.search` and adding `^` explicitly when you want it.

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 9):

the docs is clear i think.

> re.match(pattern, string[, flags])¶
>
> ```
> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of string** match the
> ```
>
> regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note
>   that this is different from a zero-length match.